# Isometric embedding probability distributions with tree transportation cost into $\ell_1$

Tags: probability-distributions, metric-spaces, trees, isometry

I was trying to solve the following problem, but don't quite know how to get started with working with the transportation metric.

> Let $T = ([n], E)$ be an unweighted, undirected tree with root $r \in [n]$, and shortest path metric $d$.  Let $p, q \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$ be two probability distributions over the vertices $[n]$ (i.e. $p_i \geq 0$, $\sum_i p_i = 1$). Define the transportation distance between $p$ and $q$ as 
>   $$
> \tau(p, q)= \inf \left\{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} d(i, j) w_{ij} : w_{ij} \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n w_{ij} = q_j, \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij} = p_i \right\}.
> $$
>   Let $\Delta_n$ denote the space of probability distributions on $[n]$. Show that there is some integer $k$ such that the metric space $(\Delta_n, \tau)$ isometrically embeds into $(\mathbf{R}^k, d_1)$, where 
>   $$
> d_1(x, y) := \sum_1^k |x_i - y_i|
> $$
>   for $x, y \in \mathbf{R}^k$.

I also don't quite know why the tree part is so relevant.